# Is there a way to implant a loop variable into a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do a loop that makes my life easier for this tic-tac-toe game, and instead of writing out every single variable I'd thought there might be a way to use a loop. I am a beginner and I'm trying to learn more.

```
const board = [
    "", "", "",

    "", "", "",

    "", "", "" 
];

// 0 = X, 1 = O

const turn = 0;

const reset = document.getElementById('reset');
const button1 = document.getElementById("1");
const button2 = document.getElementById("2");
const button3 = document.getElementById("3");
const button4 = document.getElementById("4");
const button5 = document.getElementById("5");
const button6 = document.getElementById("6");
const button7 = document.getElementById("7");
const button8 = document.getElementById("8");
const button9 = document.getElementById("9");

reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
    board = [
        "", "", "",
    
        "", "", "",
    
        "", "", "" 
    ];
})

setInterval(() => {
    // loop in here
}, 100);
```

Comment: Why don't you put the button references into an array instead of separate variables like that?

Comment: I tried that but It was giving me errors that I didn't understand.

Comment: Well any time you feel like typing in variable declarations like "a1", "a2", "a3", etc, you probably want an array. If you're getting errors, then that should be your question here.

Comment: Ok, Let me try it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const board = [
    "", "", "",

    "", "", "",

    "", "", "" 
];

// 0 = X, 1 = O

const turn = 0;

const reset = document.getElementById('reset');

const buttons = [
    button1 = document.getElementById("1"),
    button2 = document.getElementById("2"),
    button3 = document.getElementById("3"),
    button4 = document.getElementById("4"),
    button5 = document.getElementById("5"),
    button6 = document.getElementById("6"),
    button7 = document.getElementById("7"),
    button8 = document.getElementById("8"),
    button9 = document.getElementById("9")
]


reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
    board = [
        "", "", "",
    
        "", "", "",
    
        "", "", "" 
    ];
})

setInterval(() => {
    for (i=0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        board[i] = buttons[i].textContent;
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Do I have to add the `button1` and so on, or can I just put the document part?